# Is Dell D3100 docking station is compatible with Lenovo Thinkpad L440

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad, lenovo-laptop, docking-station

I am looking to buy Dell D3100 docking station for my Lenovo Thinkpad L440.

Please let me know, if, Dell D3100 docking station is compatible with Lenovo laptops.

My Laptop configuration is :
Model: Lenovo Thinkpad L440
Ram: 16GB
USB 3.0: 1 port
HDMI port: 1 (mini)

thanks

Comment: The Dell D3100 is a USB 3.0 docking station, there is absolutely no reason it would NOT be compatible with your Thinkpad L440, since the L440 has a single USB 3.0 port.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Ramhound regarding the dock should be compatible.  Looking at Dell's [Dell's Details Page](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverId=8YRVR&fileId=1963969695&osCode=WB32A&productCode=dell-usb3-dock-3100&languageCode=en&categoryId=DK) it does list Win 7 as a supported OS.  You can also download the drivers from that same page.

edit: Forgot to mention, the reason it should work is due to it connecting to the laptop via USB.  Since there is not a special hardware connector (like some other Docks), the only issue would be installing the drivers.  Since the page referenced above lists drivers for your OS I am very confident that it will work.